# measure of the set of unit vectors whose inner product with a closed curve consists of an interval of constansy

Tags: geometry, analysis

Let $\lambda : [0 , 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed curve. Let $B$ be  the set of unit vectors b such that $b \cdot \lambda : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has an interval of constansy. Prove that $B$ is of measure zero in $S^{n-1}$.

Note that the measure on the $S^{n-1}$ is the usual spherical measure.

---

EDIT I:
If you follow the below comments, you may notice that in the definition of a closed curve the function $\lambda$ itself should **not** have any interval of constancy.

Comment: I see you're new to MSE, so let me make a suggestion: Generally when someone takes the time to give an answer to your question, it's a bit rude to change the question after the fact, as it makes the answer given appear stupid/wrong. Changing it in the way you did is a little more polite, but it still automatically dismisses the question-answerer's effort (my answer **can't** be the accepted answer to the revised question). A generally more polite way to handle this is to ask a new question (pointing back to the old one perhaps to note the difference!).

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Let 
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases} \exp(-x^{-2}) & x > 0 \\
0 & x \le 0\end{cases}
$$
Then $h$ is infinitely differentiable, and $h(x)$ is positive for $x > 0$.

Let $g(x) = h(x) h(\frac{1}{2}- x)$. Then $g$ is smooth, nonnegative, and is nonzero only for $0 < x < \frac12$.

Let $K = \int_0^1 g(x) ~ dx$; then $K > 0$. Finally, let 
$$
s(x) = \frac{2\pi}{K} g(x).
$$
Then we have

1. $s$ is constant on $[1/2, 1]$.
2. $s$ maps $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 2\pi]$.
3. $s$ is smooth.

Let $\lambda: [0 1] \to \Bbb R^2: t \mapsto (\cos s(t), \sin s(t))$. Then $\lambda$ is a closed curve (indeed, the image is the unit circle, the archetypal closed curve), and $t \mapsto b \cdot \lambda(t)$ is constant on $[\frac12, 1]$ for every unit vector $b$.

I think perhaps you've got a hidden assumption about $\lambda$ that you have not disclosed.

Comment: Well, Thank you for your answer but I there are some points in your answer that are vague for me: 1- $h(x)$ is nonzere whenever x is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. 2- Thus I think $s$ is not constant on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Comment: And I think $g$ must be $h(x)h(\frac{1}{2}-x)$. so that those assumptions become true. About the origin of my question,  I think it is mentioned implicitly in a paper of Milnor "On the total curvature of knots".@John

Comment: You're right about the $\frac12 - x$; I've fixed that. Perhaps Milnor's definition of  curve requires an everywhere nonzero derivative; that would rule out this example, and is the kind of "hidden assumption" that I think might be missing.

Comment: I think the only assumption that he has on the definition of a closed curve is that the function $\lambda$ should not have any constant interval, which in the case of your answer your $\lambda$ function has indeed an interval of constancy.

Comment: Oh, well. Now you know why he had that assumption (and why you should have included it in the question).

Answer (score 1):

With the above edit, I came up with an answer to my question. In my answer, I suppose that the spherical measure is complete which I think it's true.

**Answer**:

Let $A$ be the set of open intervals in $[0,1]$ which both their endpoints are rational. Now assume $b$ is such that there exists an open interval $I$ such that $b.\lambda$ is constant on that interval. then there exists an open interval with rational endpoints such that $b.\lambda$ is constant on that. Because $\lambda$ has no interval of constancy, there exists $t_{1},t_{2}$ so that $\lambda(t_{1}) \neq \lambda(t_{2})$. Let $v = \frac{\lambda(t_{1})-\lambda(t_{2})}{|\lambda(t_{1})-\lambda(t_{2})|}$ and define $S_{v}^{n-2}$ as the intersection of unit sphere with the hyperplane with the normal vector $v$. Then $b \in S_{v}^{n-2}$. and more generally $b$  is in the intersection of all such vectors $v$. So $b$ is in a set of measure zero on the sphere(Here I used the assumption of completeness of  the measure).

Now for every $b$ in $B$ let $I_{b}$ be an interval with rational endpoints so that $b$ is constant on $I_{b}$. By the above argument one can simply deduce that :
$$ B = \bigcup \limits_{b \in B} \bigcap \limits_{t_{1},t_{2} \in I_{b}, \lambda(t_{1}) \neq \lambda(t_{2}), v=\frac{\lambda(t_{1})-\lambda(t_{2})}{|\lambda(t_{1})-\lambda(t_{2})|}}S_{v}^{n-2}.$$

Because the RHS of the above equality is a countable collection of measure zero sets, so the LHS is also a measure zero set and we are done.